# Installing Industrial Craft for Minecraft 1.7.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-industrialcraft

My son (9) has Minecraft 1.7.2 and has asked me to install Industrial Craft. What version of Industrial Craft is required (must it be 1.7.2)?

Is there an easy place for me to get it with clear installation instructions?

Comment: you'll need minecraftforge as well but I don't think IC2 has a 1.7 version yet (and it's undergoing some massive changes right now)

Comment: Life gets a lot simpler by using the [Technic Platform launcher](http://www.technicpack.net/), which provides modpacks such as [Tekki](http://www.technicpack.net/tekkit) that already come with some mods included - the disadvantage is that they usually use older Minecraft versions, e.g. Tekkit currently still uses 1.5.2

Comment: @ratchetfreak Correct. Following various of those involved in the port of FML indicates it will be several weeks at least. And on prior expeience several weeks after that for FML to stabilise. And then the mods need to be ported; this will be significant effort. Have you considered sticking to V1.6.4?

Comment: I would try creating a 1.4 profile and using the mod on that.

Answer (score 3):

The latest (experimental!) version of industrial craft is currently only available for minecraft 1.6 on the [IC2 forum](http://forum.industrial-craft.net/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=9843). Installation instructions are available [here](http://forum.industrial-craft.net/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=444), but for new users it might be smartest to install something like the [Feed the Beast](http://feed-the-beast.com/) launcher.

This launcher will do all the complicated things for you like install Forge and downloading the proper version of minecraft and various mods.
This can be installed in a different folder than minecraft and they won't interfere with each other.
Newer worlds aren't compatible with older versions so you'll need to create a new world for feed the beast I'm afraid.

Comment: I agree with feed the beast. Get the latest feed the beast, this includes MC and a lot of mods. Within the launcher you can activate and deactivate the mods. At default most mods are activated. You might want to leave them on so he can enjoy all that FTB has to offer.

Answer (score 0):

On the [wiki](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Main_Page) for the mod, they have very helpful information for versions and support. The version of IndustrialCraft does not correlate with the version of Minecraft whatsoever, as the mod may have put out more updates than Minecraft.

Here is the link to the [download page](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Download).

Comment: The IC2 wiki is essentially useless. There hasn't been a formal release of IC2 for ages. However builds for later MC are available. Eg. the IC2 "Experimental" branch (with lots of changes) seems quite stable: [builds are available online](http://ic2api.player.to:8080/job/IC2_experimental/). I'm running MC 1.6.4 with FML 9.11.1.916 and IC2-Exp 2.0.272.